# Closing Electron app does not stop the script

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, electron

I have a bit of a problem that I hope someone could help me with.

I have an Electron + React desktop application, and I need to handle properly its closing.
When I close the aplication (click on the X on the window) the program stops, however, the terminal windows that I used to run the program doesnt stop.

I use this script to run the program:

```
npm run electron-dev
```

That does:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "electron-dev": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""
 }
```

I run my app normally, when I close the window, my terminal goes:

```
wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron . exited with code 0
```

But I cant type on my terminal unless I kill the program with a Control + C.

Here is how I'm handling the app closing:

```
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
     app.quit();
   }
});

app.on('before-quit', () => {
    mainWindow.removeAllListeners('close');
    mainWindow.close();
});
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: I have experienced this problem in multiple platforms, specially Windows and Linux

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `concurrently`, this is expected behaviour.

When you close the window (and quit the program on macOS), the electron process does stop, however the the command you gave in the terminal is still running because you are still running `react-scripts`.

Look at your `electron-dev` script, you say you want to run the commands `npm start` and `wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\`. When you close the electron app, it tells you that the process ended (`wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron . exited with code 0`). However you have only ended 1 of the 2 processes you created. The process created `npm start` is still running and therefore terminal control isn't returned back to you.

`npm start` executes the command `react-scripts start`, which sets up the development environment and starts a server. You have [a few options for killing the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544145/how-stop-after-running-react-scripts-start), CTRL+C is the easiest of them.

When you package your app, you wont have this issue, the app will close cleanly when the user closes the window (or quits the program on macOS)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is there any way that I can close the process from inside the app, without packaging it?

Comment: Maybe, but it would be really hacky. Why would you want to tho? You can just use CTRL+C to kill both processes in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way to resolve this is to use the `--kill-others`/`-k` option in your `concurrently` script.

In my package file, under scripts:

`"dev": "concurrently   \"npm run client\" \"wait-on tcp:3000 && electron .\" -k",`

On any type of exit of the related processes, the others will stop too. This can be further controlled by the `--kill-others-on-fail`, as described in their documentation:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

```
Killing other processes
  -k, --kill-others          kill other processes if one exits or dies [boolean]
      --kill-others-on-fail  kill other processes if one exits with non zero
                             status code                               [boolean]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late for who made the question, but for others still out there searching for a solution:

You can use npm-run-all.

Here is the documentation for this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all).