# How to Delete React Folder?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cmd

I'm learning React JS where I made 1 project folder named **testing** & it runs successfully. However when I started to create another project folder named **hello**, suddenly I ran into an error on both **testing** & **hello** projects & both said, **localhost refused to connect**. Maybe because I created both project folders in the same folder named **training** & I want to delete the **hello** project. Because I'm new to React, I want to know how to delete the **hello** project folder...

Here are my directory for both project folders btw:

**C:\Users\Ernes\training\testing**

**C:\Users\Ernes\training\hello**

Comment: `localhost refused to connect` - Are you trying to run both dev servers at the same time? Press `ctrl+c` to stop the dev server for `testing` before attempting to start `hello`

Comment: Sorry if this sound embarrassing but I don't really know what I'm doing, I just follow the tutorial book & the book kinda says to create another project on the same folder. And do you mean to press ctrl+c in VS Code?

Comment: What's the tutorial book?

Comment: ReactJS guide book

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/179661 will tell you how to delete a folder

Answer (score 1):

Stop npm service, then delete hello folder. You can run different projects at same time, but you should use different port. You can find port configuration details package.json file

Comment: how to write that on command prompt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544145/how-stop-after-running-react-scripts-start

Comment: Did you say that I can create 2 projects on the same folder but the port should be different? I did also notice that both testing & hello folder have the same localhost:3000